# android ListView doesn't get updated

Tags: android, android-listview

As title says, my listview won't get filled.
I know that the adapter is getting filled with 3 items, debugged my way through it. But my xml isnt showing anything at all:

The adapter is a global variable if that should do anything.
Code:

```
private void listChange(CustomCursor c){

    List<SimpleListItem> itemsList = new ArrayList<SimpleListItem>();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String picture = c.getString("picture");
        String text = c.getString("name");
        itemsList.add(new SimpleListItem(text, picture));

    }
    productListAdapter = new ProductAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.product_item, itemsList);
    setListAdapter(productListAdapter);
    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

XML of the activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <dk.foo.views.PageHeaderView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </dk.foo.views.PageHeaderView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add the full layout file where you declare the `ListView`.

Comment: sorry stackoverflow code insertion error ;)

Comment: Include full source code.that would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `orientation` of your `LinearLayout` to `vertical` if you want to see the `ListView`.

Right now with the `orientation` of your parent `LinearLayout` set to `horizontal` and the `width` of your custom view `PageHeaderView` set to `FILL_PARENT`, your `ListView` is pushed out of the screen.